# Oracle databse connectvity via shell

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, unix

What are the pre-requisites to write a shell script that connects to oracle database, runs a query and displays the output on screen

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [You can use SQL*Plus to do this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm). Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis That's it, I already found that on stackoverflow. Nothing else required, drivers, libraries ? There is no comprehensive list that suggests how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are working on a machine with a suitable client installed. As Bob commented, SQLPlus is Oracle's command line client. It gets installed with the database, but if you are working from a different machine you may need to install the client locally.

Once you have that available you just have to set up the environment variables and work from there.

For example, given

```
export ORA_BASE=/db/oracle
export ORA_HOME=$ORA_BASE/product/12.1.0.2/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=$dbName

PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

and assuming the default test db has been installed as $dbName,

```
echo "select * from dual;" | 
  sqlplus scott/tiger@//${dbHost:=$HOSTNAME}:${port:=1521}/$ORACLE_SID
```

My confirmation in Ansible that I have connectivity on a dev install looks like this:

```
export ORACLE_BASE='{{ ORA_BASE }}'
export ORACLE_HOME='{{ ORA_HOME }}'
export ORACLE_SID='{{ SID }}'
PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

echo "Testing remote access to $HOSTNAME/$SID via sqlplus"

echo "select * from dual;" | sqlplus scott/tiger@//$HOSTNAME:1521/$ORACLE_SID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PLSQL `script.sql` contains the query and formatting. Assuming `sqlplus` in the path and all the Oracle environments variables are correct.

The correct pattern is:

```
echo exit | sqlplus scott/tiger@//$HOSTNAME:1521/$ORACLE_SID @script.sql
```

#### Explanations:

`echo exit` transmit exit command to `sqlplus` when the script terminates. Returning the prompt to the shell.

`sqlplus` call Oracle scripting shell/utility .

`scott/tiger@//$HOSTNAME:1521/$ORACLE_SID` sqlplus connectivity string to user `scott` with password `tiger` to database in server `$HOSTNAME` on port `1521` with SID `$ORACLE_SID`

`@script.sql` invoking the PLSQL script stored in file `script.sql`